# Understanding output given by valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am writing a Monte Carlo simulation engine, and I am experiencing what I believe to be memory leaks in my software. For example, I am running a certain calculation, and it turns out that unless I have a

`std::cout <<"Some string" << std::endl;`

in the region where the computation is written, my code does not work.

There must be an error/memory leak in my program if I am seeing such behavior. So, I decided to run valgrind. This how I compiled it all:
`g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wdisabled-optimization -Werror -pedantic -Ofast -march=native -fopenmp·-g main.cpp misc.cpp classes.cpp -o cosolv_ani`
Then I ran it as:
`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -s --log-file=valgrind.out ./cosolv_ani -f 1 -M 1 -p 4mer.txt -t geom_and_esurf.txt -u energydump.mc -e orientation.mc -s stats.mc -o coords.mc`

The output is quite large. Here is the link to it: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/tcfR5b8x.

My question is, how do I even start reading valgrind? What do these terms mean? I see references to main.cpp, misc.cpp, but I do not understand how to go about this problem...

I apologize for the wall of text, but how does one go about parsing through all of this information?

I see a reference to misc.cpp: 40. This is the line:

```
std::map <int, std::array<double,3>> Or2Dir = { {0, {1.0,0,0}}, {1, {0,1.0,0}}, {2, {0,0,1}}, {3, {-1,0,0}}, {4, {0,-1,0}}, {5, {0,0,-1}}, {6, {1.0/(std::sqrt(2)), 1.0/(std::sqrt(2)), 0}}, {7, {1.0/(std::sqrt(2)), 0, 1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {8, {1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0}}, {9, {1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0,-1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {10, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0}}, {11, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0,1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {12, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0}}, {13, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),0,-1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {14, {0,1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {15, {0,1.0/(std::sqrt(2)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {16, {0,-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)), 1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {17, {0,-1.0/(std::sqrt(2)), -1.0/(std::sqrt(2))}}, {18, {1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {19, {1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {20, {1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {21, {1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {22, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {23, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {24, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}}, {25, {-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3)),-1.0/(std::sqrt(3))}} };
```

I have made a map that assigns an integer to one of the 26 directions on a cubic lattice (diagonals included). Is there an error with initializing a map this way? The nature of my simulation requires me to call on these directions quite frequently.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and adding `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile command and see if that reports the same or different issues.

Comment: For memory leaks, don't worry about the "still reachable" reports; the "definitely lost" reports are the ones to take seriously.  (and make sure your program exits "normally" by returning from main() rather than by calling exit() or similar; that way all of your destructors will get a chance to execute and clean up resources before valgrind checks the heap for leaked memory)

Comment: I am working on producing a minimal example, however, the system is rather large, and I am not sure how to that succinctly, as of right now... By the way, do you suggest to simply compile and run with ```-fsanitize=address,undefined``` or do you suggest I run valgrind with these options? @RetiredNinja

Comment: You "go about parsing through all of this information" one error at a time. Step 1: start with the first one. Figure it out. Step 2: fix it. Step 3: run `valgrind` again and go back to step 1.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I do not understand the nature of the first error... :/

Comment: A very careful examination of your question failed to uncover anything that indicates what this particular error is, so I'm not sure how anyone can help you, regarding some error that's not even shown.

Comment: If you add AddressSanitizer to the compile it's probably best to not run Valgrind at the same time. I could be wrong but I try to stick to one tool at a time for checking leaks and such. One thing that can help when trying to reduce to a smaller example is to just `#if 0` half of the program and see if your tool of choice still sees issues. If the error is in the part you cut out then you know the part left is potentially clean. I try to validate one "module" at a time to quickly narrow things down and then the interactions between modules.

Comment: @bad_chemist *Is there an error with initializing a map this way?* -- There is no error there.  There is no raw memory management going on in that declaration.  Everything is by-value.  Also, unless you know what to look for, you will never find it, valgrind or no valgrind.  That's why code reviews by other persons looking at your code are so important.  If you think everything looks ok, then it will look ok and you won't consider there is something wrong with that section of code.  Someone else with experience may detect immediately there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: What OS and hardware is this on?

Comment: The information below means that (likely) there are instructions not recognised by valgrind (maybe AVX512, I did not check). So valgrind terminates abnormally. You might try to upgrade to 3.19. But if this is really AVC512, the support is not yet done. vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x62 0xF1 0xFD 0x8 0x6F 0x55 0x0 0x62 0xF1 0xFD
vex amd64->IR: REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR: VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR: PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0